# Query For Dates Based on start date and end date

Tags: sql

I have two datepickers from and to dates.And then one textbox.After selecting dates and typing some name in text box I need to filter records in table.I have Admission date in my table.I need to write query so that if the Student name matches and also if admissionDate falls between fromdate and todate then it should display the record

I am writing this query but it is not working.

```
SELECT studentId, studentName, admissionDate
from Student
where studentName like :studentName
  AND admissionDate BETWEEN (fromDate like :fromDate AND toDate like :toDate)
order by studentId desc
```

From DaoImpl I am getting fromDate and toDate values

DaoImpl

```
    @Override
    public List<Student> getSearchResultsByKeyword(String search,Date
    fromDate,Date toDate) {
    List<Student> users = new ArrayList<Student>();
    System.out.println("Student Name:"+search+"fromDate:"+fromDate);
    Query query = 
    sessionFactory.getCurrentSession().createSQLQuery(SEARCHSTUDENTS);
    query.setParameter("studentName", "%"+search+"%");
    query.setParameter("fromDate", fromDate);
    query.setParameter("toDate", toDate);
    /*query.setParameter("admissionDate","%"+search+"%");
    query.setParameter("rollNumber","%"+search+"%");
    query.setParameter("gender","%"+search+"%");*/
    query.setResultTransformer
    (Transformers.aliasToBean(Student.class));
    users = query.list();
    return users;
    }
```

Comment: What mean by * not working *. Are you getting any error ?

Comment: Your BETWEEN is very strange...

Comment: I am getting Error in sql syntax

Comment: Try `... AND admissionDate BETWEEN :fromDate AND :toDate ...`

Comment: Can you post the error you're getting?

Comment: You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use near 'like '2017-08-01 00:00:00' AND toDate like '2017-08-31 00:00:00') order by stude' at line 1

Comment: @jarlh .yup its working now.Thank you

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try without using between like this

```
SELECT studentId, studentName, admissionDate
from Student
where studentName like :studentName
  AND admissionDate >= :fromDate AND admissionDate <= :toDate
order by studentId desc
```

And make sure that date formats you are sending are the same as DB date format (e.g YYYY/MM/DD)

Comment: Bro If you know about angularjs then I have one more question in my profile like Saving of checkboxes into database using angularjs and spring mvc.If you have time please go through it bro.Its a bit of emergency